# Shopify and AWS Cognito OIDC

Tags: amazon-web-services, shopify, openid, openid-connect

I'm trying to use Shopify as an AWS Cognito User Pool "federated identity provider". Ostensibly, it seems to follow the OIDC protocol. However, there seems to be scant information on the format of the `ProviderDetails` field in the [AWS API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateIdentityProvider.html), and I can't seem to figure out how to correctly pass the Issuer for Shopify. I've tried to do it through the console as well, but keep getting the message:

> Discovery returned no results. Check the issuer and run discovery again or manually add the required fields below.

I suspect that, due to Shopify's multitenancy model, I'll never get a single set of OIDC parameters -- it seems to suggest there is a different URL for each shop.

Is there documentation on either **(a) how to set up Shopify as an OIDC provider** -- including Issuer, Authorization Endpoint, Token Endpoint, etc. -- or **(b) why Shopify does not match the OIDC standard?**

Comment: Based on my knowledge Shopify are using oauth to authinticiate the api, you cannot use open id. anyway I suggest to ask Shopify community here https://community.shopify.com/

Comment: Something related https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Using-Customer-API-with-other-user-providers-eg-AWS-Cognito/m-p/465928?collapse_discussion=true&filter=location&location=category:en&q=AWS&search_type=thread